# Overriding a buttons callback in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm writing a calculator app, which will have the numbered buttons append their values to the text-field when they are clicked. I'm trying to create a new button class with a callback that is overriden so I don't have to add the same lambda function to every single instantiation of the button, and a minimum width for all the buttons. In the canvas% the I can do this by overriding on-paint since on-paint calls the paint-callback, but I haven't found a similar solution in the button.

```
(define number-button% (class button%
                     (super-new)
                     (inherit get-label)
                     (init [min-width 30])
                     (define/override (callback)
                       (let ([value (send input-screen get-value)])
                         (send input-screen set-value (string-append value (get-label)))))))
```

And an example of what I'm trying to avoid

```
(define 7button (new button% [label "7"] [parent second-row]
                     [callback (λ (b e)
                                 (let ([value (send input-screen get-value)] [b-label (send b get-label)])
                                   (send input-screen set-value (string-append value b-label))))]))
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'll write a macro if I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight this is pretty obvious, but by passing the init arguments I want automatically assigned to the superclass, which is the button%, I can create a class which already has a minimum width, and a callback defined.

```
(define number-button% (class button%
         (super-new [callback (λ (b e)
                    (let ([value (send input-screen get-value)] [b-label (send b get-label)])
                      (send input-screen set-value (string-append value b-label))))]
                                [min-width 30])))
```

Then I can just instantiate the buttons like this.

```
(define 7button (new number-button% [label "7"] [parent second-row]))
(define 8button (new number-button% [label "8"] [parent second-row]))
(define 9button (new number-button% [label "9"] [parent second-row]))
```

I could further modify the new-button% class to automatically parent to the second-row if I wanted, but that might be too restrictive